# adding class to div element using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, class

im really new to js, and im currently making a webiste. Because i have a repeated html code for the header and footer of the wepage, i used php to call the html file rather than repeating the same code. On the other hand,i wanted the current active page to have a different color, therefor i am using javascript to get the name of the class and add the class `active` to make a exeption in css. getting the id seems to be working, but i cant find the class `active` being add. why is this?

```
<p class="activepage" id="felt">aegearg<p>    
<script>
      var element = document.getElementsByClassName("activepage")[0];
      var id = element.id;
      getElementsByClassName(id).classList.add("active");
    </script>
```

Comment: Try `element.classList.add("active");`. Get rid of lines: `var id = element.id;` and `getElementsByClassName(id).classList.add("active");`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code:

```
document.getElementById("IdElement").classList.add("ClassNameAdd");
```

Answer (score 1):

ids of the elements should be unique , search your element by id and then remove or add the desired class name

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.add('MyClass');

document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.remove('MyClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like that:

```
const element = document.QuerySelector("#activepage");
element.ClassList.add("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery

```
$('#activepage').addClass('active');
```

instead of addClass you can toggleClass for removing and adding class